# How to get QTextList's format in PySide2

Tags: python, pyside2

I want to access a QTextList format later in my application, but it seems that it is always deleted after it is created

I already know about the `format()` function

I create the QTextList this way:

```
cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
cursor.insertList(QTextListFormat.ListDisc)
```

Later in the app, I want to get back the format, that is, ListDisc, or any other; and I do:

```
list = self.textEdit.textCursor().currentList()
if(list):
    print(list.format())
```

I get this error at the line where print is called:

```
RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtGui.QTextList) already deleted.
```

EDIT: MCVE below gives me the error when run on PySide2 5.12.1 windows 7

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtGui import QTextListFormat

class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, fileName=None):
        super(Test, self).__init__()

        self.testList()

    def testList(self):

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
        cursor.createList(QTextListFormat.ListDisc)

        list = self.textEdit.textCursor().currentList()
        if(list):
            print(list.format())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    test = Test()
    test.show()
```

Comment: If you want help then provide an MCVE, I've tried it in Linux, maybe the bug does not affect Linux, anyway I recommend [reporting the bug](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/Reporting_Bugs) because in SO we can not help you in those cases because your code is correct (at least what I see).

Comment: I have added the MCVE. Please test @eyllanesc

Comment: Ok, you're right, I had tested it incorrectly. The same code works in PyQt5 but not in PySide2 so that reinforces my idea that it is a bug and unfortunately we can not help you here, I recommend reporting it to Qt: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/Reporting_Bugs. Currently PySide2 has many of these problems but with the reports probably in the future these problems no longer exist